# Didn't find MainActivity on path

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dex

I am using android studio 2.3 beta 1 along with these configurations

compileSdkVersion 25

buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

applicationId "octave.foodster"

minSdkVersion 19

targetSdkVersion 25

The problem is that when i run an app through android studio everything works fine but when i send the apk of the same app to another phone,it crashes.I am just using a basic activity so just the default template that android studio creates the moment you create a new project.i have not added any external libraries or anything else.

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The error I get is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: octave.foodster, PID: 8580
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{octave.foodster/octave.foodster.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "octave.foodster.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/octave.foodster-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/octave.foodster-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2566)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5896)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "octave.foodster.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/octave.foodster-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/octave.foodster-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1072)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2556)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5896) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: octave.foodster.MainActivity
                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                        ... 12 more
               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: Same issue i was getting try to make the apk without instant run.(Disable the instant run option)check and let me know.

Comment: Add your manifest please

Comment: How are you sending the APK? Are you extracting it from your phone? Don't do that, build an APK and share that, it will work on all phones.

Comment: @AseedUsmani the apk that was generated by android studio ( app-debug.apk ) i am sending that fille.

Comment: try: restart your android studio and then clean rebuild your project.

Comment: Go to this link.I think this will work for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729753/libgdx-android-in-eclipse-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo

Comment: @SagarGangawane that worked for me ,thank you so much,if you write the same thing as an answer i can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was getting the same issue when i was trying to run the apk with instant run enabled.

Solution:-

> Disable the instant run and install that apk in the device it will work.

Happy coding.Enjoy.